# How to check if figures are on the same page of call out/text?

Tags: macros, ref, pageref

If a figure is mentioned in a text, say page 10, but the corresponding figure appears on page 11, how can I automatically introduce some additional text (e.g.: on page 11) beside the figure mention in the text.

Instead of doing this:
`Figure \ref{fig:test} on page \pageref{fig:test} shows bla bla.`

Autocheck:
`Figure \\ref{fig:test} \check shows bla bla.`

Where `\check` is a macro to check the co-existence of the figure referencing and figure (float), whether they are on the same page. If true, return Null, else return `on page \pageref{fig:test}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with the [varioref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package?

Comment: Hi.. @Mico.. not heard of it.. however, looks like it's the solution to my question. Thank you. I'll go test it!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [`varioref` package](//ctan.org/pkg/varioref) and its `\vpageref` command to reference the page associated with another `\label`. It does a check to see whether the reference is on the same page. If so, the default text (`on this page`) is printed. You can override this globally, or locally by supplying an optional argument. You're most likely looking for `\vpageref[]{<label>}` with an *empty* optional argument (so as to print nothing).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

See Figure~\ref{fig:figure} on page~\pageref{fig:figure}.

See Figure~\ref{fig:figure} \vpageref{fig:figure}.

See Figure~\ref{fig:figure} \vpageref[]{fig:figure}.% Note the empty optional argument

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Since `\vpageref` itself sets a `\label` in order to compare the page numbers its referencing, you'll need to compile twice with every change in the location of `\vpageref`.

Answer (score 2):

OpTeX users can create following definition of the `\check` macro:

```
\def\check{\label[x/\_lastreflabel]\wlabel{}%
   \space
   \ea\ifx\csname _pgref:x/\_lastreflabel\ea\endcsname 
          \csname _pgref:\_lastreflabel\endcsname
   \else on page \pgref[\_lastreflabel] \fi
}

% Test:

Figure \ref[fig:label]\check shows bla bla.

%\vfil\break   %% <-- you can comment out this to show the effect

... a figure ...
\cskip
\caption/f [fig:label] Figure blba bla

\bye
```

Of course, you have to run TeX twice when changes were done.

The macro `\check` creates its own label `x/label` an writes its position to the `.ref` file using `\wlabel{}`. The following `\ifx` checks it the reference macros `\_pgref:x/label` and `\_pgref:label` are the same. If it is true then it does nothing else it writes the text `on page \pgref[label]` .