# Is there a way to change the style of a float depending on whether it is on the same page of call out or not?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

This question is somewhat related to [How to check if figures are on the same page of call out/text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/605781/18401) but for another purpose and its answer is irrelevant here (though probably the solution to my answer is deeply buried in the code of `varioref`), hence the current new question.

Is there a way to change the style of a float (e.g. with a caption text in bold face) depending on whether it is on the same page of call out or not?

Here is a skeleton of what I'm after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfOnTheSamePage}{ m m }{%
  (Maybe in bold face...)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{%
    \IfOnTheSamePage{}{\bfseries}%
    Caption%
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: set a label,then check the `\pageref` with the current page and fix up the typesetting on the next run if they are the same

Comment: Considering the time of day, it was too obvious! :) Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well, maybe a complete answer with a MCE would be helpful to other people. David, would you proceed? If not, I could proceed. And I don't consider this question as off-topic...